# Render XML, setting a value for a non-database field

Tags: xml, activerecord

I have a model 'Feast' which has a method 'date_for_year(year)' which calculates the year. It's not just a database field for each year, but needs to be calculated on the fly.

Having the usual view file I can just iterate through the @feasts object and output each date just by calling feast.date_for_year(year) in each line.

But how would I do that for auto-generated XML output? I need a way to pass a year to the whole set, so that the date is listed as a field in my XML output, too. Does anyone know how to do that?

At the moment I have nothing more than just the starter line

```
render :xml => Feast.where(:date_for_year => params[:year]).all
```

which obviously can't work that way, when it's not a database field. Well, it's not even well thought anyway, but I am stuck here, as I cannot even imagine how to do it correctly. Maybe I could solve it if anyone's just able to tell me how to solve it in theory.

Thanks very much for your help

- Arne

Answer (score 0):

I just solved it on my own. There were two ways to do it.

1. Adding my custom method to @attributes after setting the year.
2. Custom XML output.

I preferred the latter, as it was a cleaner way to implement it, imho. Here's how I did it: http://danengle.us/2009/05/generating-custom-xml-for-your-rails-app/